# React Native Maps onRegionChangeComplete Fails to Fire on Second Drawing

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In my React Native app, I've built a city search using React Native Maps and the Google Places API.

I use a city's latitude and longitude I get from Google to render the map.

The `onRegionChangeComplete` callback fires the first time I draw the map for a city. However, if I search a second city and then the first city a second time, `onRegionChangeComplete` fails to fire for the second visit to the first city.

It's as though the tiles for that city are cached and therefore the map does not fire a change.

This seems like a bug in React Native maps, but I thought to post here. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

For context, the reason I need that event to fire is because I populate the map with markers that fall within the map boundaries. I wait for a map change to complete before determining which markers to show.

Currently, the map remains empty on second visit to a city because the callback I chose is not firing.

Comment: I too think that `onRegionChangeComplete` is buggy. I have a map locked to a statick region with disabled user controls, yet `onRegionChangeComplete` fires three times in a row after mounting the component.